# Map Reduce using UnderscoreJS

Tags: underscore.js

I am trying to convert the following dataset:

```
var foo = {
        "2011":
            [{ "date": "2011-08-01T00:00:00", "y": "100" },
             { "date": "2011-08-05T00:00:00", "y": "400" },
             { "date": "2011-09-01T00:00:00", "y": "900" }
            ],
        "2012": 
           [{ "date": "2012-07-22T00:00:00", "y": "200" },
            { "date": "2012-09-22T00:00:00", "y": "430" },
            { "date": "2012-10-26T00:00:00", "y": "100" }
           ]
       }
```

into something like this:

```
var foo1 = {
        "2011":
            [{ "y": "1400" }],
        "2012": 
            [{ "y": "730" }]
       }
```

What would be the best way to do this using UnderscoreJS? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to reduce to an array?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Trying to render several reports client-side in a dashboard and need to be able to modify the dataset without having to make repeated server calls for each report.

Comment: Why are those numbers strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore does not have a utility for object mapping unfortunately. We'd have to emulate that with `_.object(_.keys(…), _.map(_.values(…), …))` or by `_.clone`ing the object, iterating it by `_.each` and manually assigning. Let's better extend the lib to get more readable code:

```
_.mixin({
    mapObject: function(obj, iterator, context) {
        return _.each(_.clone(obj), function(items, p, o) {
             o[p] = iterator.apply(this, arguments);
        }, context);
    }
});

var foo1 = _.mapObject(foo, function(items) {
    return [{y: _.reduce(_.map(_.pluck(items, "y"), Number), function(m, y) {
         return m + y;
    }, 0) }];
});
```

Comment: Just what the OP wanted: a map and a reduce (though not a map-reduce). Better now with the helper function?

Comment: I was trying to make a joke, but no, it's still to me, totally unreadable but it works and feels overly complicated just because it's underscore, but correct nonetheless.

Comment: Please, come up with an easier solution, I'd appreciate it :-) I've further simplified it, now using an actual map-reduce. More readable now?